# Showing some number on snackbar when I am getting location from Location listener

Tags: java, android, google-maps, locationmanager, locationlistener

I am using a map and location listener. I am calling the location listener when the map is ready and showing marker's on map after getting the location from location listener , all this in `setMap()` method.

When I am getting the location I see some numbers on `snackbar`, I dont know from where it is coming, nowhere I am showing it. I am showing snackbar's to show the internet and gps alert. But this is coming from nowhere.

Looks like this:

[image]

What is it??

Code:

```
public class SearchMerchantFragment extends Fragment implements GetSearchedMerchantsAsyncTask.GetSearchedMerchantsCallBack, OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)

    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_merchant, container, false);

        setUpUI(view);

        return view;
    }


    public void setUpUI(View view) {

        setUpMapIfNeeded();


        sessionData = new SessionData(getActivity());
        sessionUserId = sessionData.getString("user_id", "-1");
        access_token = sessionData.getString("api_key", "-1");


        mLocationsList = new ArrayList<>();
        markers = new ArrayList<>();

        edtSearch = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);
        parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
        rv_fetch_merchants = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_fetch_merchants);
        merchantsList = new ArrayList<Merchants>();
        merchantsAdapter = new SearchedMerchantsAdapter(this.getContext(), merchantsList);
        rv_fetch_merchants.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        rv_fetch_merchants.setAdapter(merchantsAdapter);
        rv_fetch_merchants.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv_fetch_merchants.setItemViewCacheSize(30);
        rv_fetch_merchants.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        rv_fetch_merchants.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);


    }

    //get searched merchants
    public void accessMerchants() {

       new GetSearchedMerchantsAsyncTask(getActivity(), SearchMerchantFragment.this).execute(access_token, sessionUserId, String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));

    }

    @Override
    public void doPostExecute(ArrayList<Merchants> merchantsArrayList) {

        merchantsList.clear();
        merchantsList.addAll(merchantsArrayList);
        merchantsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        for (Merchants merchants : merchantsList) {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(merchants.getLatitude(), merchants.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)).title(merchants.getKirana_name());
            Marker m = mGoogleMap.addMarker(marker);
            markers.add(m);
        }

    }

    public void showAlert(String alert) {

        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(parentLayout, alert, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.show(); // Don’t forget to show!
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mGoogleMap == null) {
            mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        }
    }

    //setup map

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;

        buildGoogleApiClient();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        mapConnected = true;

        if (mapConnected) {
            if (CommonUtils.isConnectedToInternet(getActivity())) {

                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    initializeLocationManager();
                    requestLocation();
                }
                else {
                    ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).showAlert(getResources().getString(R.string.locationAlert));
                }
            } else {
                ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).showAlert(getResources().getString(R.string.check_network));
            }
        }


    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        //   Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"buildGoogleApiClient",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"onConnected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"onConnectionSuspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        //    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"onConnectionFailed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mapConnected = false;
        mGoogleMap = null;

        View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

    public void setMap() {

        try {      

                    mLatLang = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
                    accessMerchants();


                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    markerOptions.position(mLatLang);
                    markerOptions.title(getResources().getString(R.string.position));
                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
                    mMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(mLatLang).zoom(14).build();

                    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));



                    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                    mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);


                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[0]);
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[1]);


        } catch (SecurityException e) {

        }
    }

    private void initializeLocationManager() {

        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }

        boolean gps_enabled = false;
        boolean network_enabled = false;

        try {
            gps_enabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        try {
            network_enabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
            // notify user


            ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).showAlert(getResources().getString(R.string.locationAlert));
        }

    }

    public class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {

        public LocationListener() {
        }

        public LocationListener(String provider) {
            Log.e(Application.TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.e(Application.TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);

            mLastLocation.set(location);

            if(mapConnected)
            setMap();

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(Application.TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);

        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(Application.TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);

        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.e(Application.TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }
    }

    public void requestLocation() {

        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(Application.TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(Application.TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                    mLocationListeners[1]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(Application.TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(Application.TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

As I did debug I found that I get this in `onLocationChanged` method when the `setMap()` method is called, before or after the method is called.

Which number is this?? Please help thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this in your code:

```
getString(R.string.locationAlert);
```

With this.

```
getResources().getString(R.string.locationAlert);
```

The issue is `getString(R.string.locationAlert);` this code returns the R file integer assigned space.

Comment: damn, one second to late :D

Comment: this was the easy one.

Comment: but i do call like this in another fragments too there it works perfect.

Comment: there must be some issue. but actual code is this. getResources links to res forlder and getString will access the String.xml file and R.String.string_name will link you to the string reference which you were printing lasting. I you want to make it clear then go to you R file and check the above printed integer that will be the reference to the string which you were printing.